# Point domain and subdomain to different ports (app) using nginx on EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, cloudflare

**Setup:**

EC2 box with an elastic IP.

I have a domain `example.com`. I want it to map to a nodejs app running on port `3000`. I have a subdomain `email.example.com` that should map to port `3001`.

Zone records:

[image]

**Relevant config files:**

`/etc/hosts`

`127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 email.example.com`

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name email.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

}
```

This does not work. `example.com` goes to port `3000` but `email.example.com` does too (instead of port `3001`).

Then I tried moving the `server` blocks into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d/email.example.com.conf` but same result. Then I tried `/etc/nginx/sites-enables/example.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/email.example.com` but same thing.

I am not sure how to get this done. Researched a lot online and tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: your config should be correct, did you make sure you reloaded the new config after saving ?

Comment: You mean restart nginx? Yes, I did that.

Comment: I think something is probably wrong with the DNS settings. Both the domain and subdomain have A record pointing to the same IP. Is that how it should be?

Comment: yes, for my vps for eample i have `domain.com` and `*.domain.com` pointing to my server

Comment: restart and reload are slightly different, `restart` shuts down the server and starts it again, while `reload` loads the new settings without closing the server

Comment: I tried `reload` but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Ok as a final measure, I'm moving my DNS from cloudflare to the domain registrar itself. Could be a weird caching issue.

Comment: if you want to make sure, use a cache buster param, for example `email.example.com?test`

Comment: Same issue. I also changed my config (as a test) so example.com `proxies_pass`es to `google.com`. That's not happening either.

Comment: then your request isn't matching that server block, check what might be wrong, like `www` or `https` all these might make a difference, to prove my theory, swap the server blocks order, put the whole server block for `email.example.com` at the top and reload/restart, all request should match email only, if so then you have a problem with the `server_name`

Comment: Nope. Moved the `email.domain.com` block on top but still no difference. Could it be the DNS? Here's the precise DNS config: http://i.imgur.com/35VQZpu.png

Comment: As another test, I removed both the `server` blocks, reloaded and restarted, and tried accessing the site. And it's being served. This is getting weirder now.

Comment: maybe you forgot files inside `conf.d` or `sites-enabled`

Comment: Update. `nginx.conf`: https://gist.github.com/karan/521594057330c7935a10. In `sites-enabled`: https://gist.github.com/karan/cc4c669c3568043fa641 (I have `email.domain.com` file and `domain.com` file. Still no change.